# How can you make function calls from app.js to another file without using module.exports?

Tags: node.js

I want to make function calls from app.js to another js file in the same project without using modeule.export. Is there a way to do so? Possibly by including the file in package.json?

I'm not able to find a way to include other js files in package.json "scripts" list. Maybe that would allow function calls to be made across files.

Comment: Module.exports IS the mechanism to allow function reuse across files. If your objective is to reuse browser based libraries in node.js you can easily modify them to conditionally use module.exports so that they can be used in both node.js and the browser.

Comment: why do you not want to use module.exports??

Comment: You can make things global, but `module.exports` is far easier and better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nope**

Sorry to let you down, but you have to use `module.exports`